# How to target the Nth element in a webcomponent shadowDOM with CSS ::part()

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component, shadow-dom

My `<web-component></webcomponent>` is very simply built, a series of `<input type="text part="input" />` directly in the `#shadow-root`.

I can style them all at one without any troubles with:

```
web-component::part(input) {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

But neither of these works if I want to target a specific input:

```
web-component::part(input):nth-child(3) {}
web-component::part(input):nth-of-type(3) {}
web-component::part(input).input-3 {} /* with class properly defined in the web component */
web-component::part(input.input-3) {}
web-component::part(input:nth-of-type(3)) {}
...
```

Can't find any documentation about this.

EDIT : I forgot to mention that the inputs are not slotted, they're generated dynamically.

```js
customElements.define("web-component", 
        class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
                this.size = this.getAttribute('size');
                this.template = document.createElement("template");
                this.template.innerHTML = '<style>'
                +':host {white-space: nowrap}'
                +'input {text-align:center;width: 3ch;height: 3ch}'
                +'input:not(:last-child){margin-right:.5ch}'
                +'</style>'
                this.render();
            }

            render() {
            
                this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.template.content.cloneNode(true));

                for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
                    const input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.setAttribute('part','input');
                    input.classList.add('input-'+(i+1));
                    input.type = "text";
                    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(input);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

```css
web-component::part(input) {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
web-component::part(input):nth-child(1) {
  background: #ff00ff;
}
web-component::part(input):nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
web-component::part(input).input-3 {
  background: #00ff00;
}
web-component::part(input.input-4) {
  background: #00ffff;
}
web-component::part(input:nth-of-type(5)) {
  background: #ff00ff;
}
web-component::part(input:nth-chlid(6)) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<web-component size="6"></web-component>
```

Comment: I'd just do `web-component .input-4` myself, but I'm ancient and don't know anything about this newfangled `::part` nonsense :).

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: Thank you @Rob you're just blowing my mind with this information. I always thought I was doing good. Is it also true for <hr/> and <br/> for example?

Comment: Yes. All HTML self-closing tags do not need or use a closing slash and never have. You can put one there (due to legacy XHTML reasons) but it does nothing, has no meaning and browsers ignore it so it's useless and pointless to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done this way. From W3C [css-shadow-parts spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shadow-parts/#part):

> The ::part() pseudo-element can take additional **pseudo**-classes after it, such as x-button::part(label):hover, but never matches the structural pseudo-classes or any other pseudo-classes that match **based on tree information** rather than local element information.

All selectors you're using won't be matched because they are either not pseudo-classes or pseudo-classes that based on tree information. One big reason for this is to allow the element creator to fully control what parts are exposed to be styled outside.

Fortunately, part names act similarly to classes: multiple elements can have the same part name, and a single element can have multiple part names.

Hence, you can use multiple part names such as `part(input input-1)`. These can still be combined with non-structural pseudo-classes such as `:focus` or `:hover`.

```js
customElements.define("web-component", 
        class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
                this.size = this.getAttribute('size');
                this.template = document.createElement("template");
                this.template.innerHTML = '<style>'
                +':host {white-space: nowrap}'
                +'input {text-align:center;width: 3ch;height: 3ch}'
                +'input:not(:last-child){margin-right:.5ch}'
                +'</style>'
                this.render();
            }

            render() {
            
                this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.template.content.cloneNode(true));

                for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
                    const input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.setAttribute('part','input input-'+(i+1));
                    input.type = "text";
                    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(input);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

```css
web-component::part(input) {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

web-component::part(input input-1)  {
  background: #ff00ff;
}

web-component::part(input input-2):hover{
  background:green;
}

web-component::part(input input-3):focus{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<web-component size="6" id="shadow-dom-host"></web-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:part()` can not be extended with pseudoselectors, neither can it contain anything but part-references, because the whole point of `:part` is to only target specific **named** DOM elements inside shadowDOM

You also have another issue

Like 9 out of 10 developers your are falling into the DOM parsed trap,
they experience no issues because they all define their Web Components (too) late.

There is no DOM when the Web Component is defined **before** DOM is parsed,
Below `Run code snippet` can't get a `size` attribute in the `constructor`.

```html
<script>
customElements.define("web-component",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    get size() {
      return this.getAttribute('size') || "No attribute size!";      
    }
    constructor() {
      super();
      console.log("constructor:", this.size );
    }
    connectedCallback(){
      console.log("connected size attribute:", this.size );
      const log = x => console.log(x, "innerHTML.length:", this.innerHTML.length , "characters");
      log("connectedCallback");
      setTimeout( () => log("after a setTimeout") );
    }
  }
);
</script>

<web-component size="6"><b>Web Components Rule!</b></web-component>
```

#### connectedCallback

Only in the connectedCallback are **the attributes** available.

Note! There is no `.innerHTML` lightDOM yet!
Because the connectedCallback **fires on the opening tag**
[See my Dev.to blogpost](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-developers-do-not-connect-with-the-connectedcallback-yet-4jo7)

But its save to attach shadowDOM here. And create DOM with a handy helper function `createElement`

And you do **not** want to use `appendChild` inside a loop, because it causes unnecessary reflow/paints for every item.

I have added an extra **attribute** option for styling: `select="4"`  **not** based on `part`
Which works because each `<input>` adds a CSS rule to the style in shadowDOM
e.g. `:host([select*="4"]) #inp4 { background:lightgreen }`

```
<web-component size="6" select="4"></web-component>
<web-component select="23"></web-component>
<web-component size="2"></web-component>
```

[image]

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("web-component", class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
        let css = 'input {text-align:center;width:3ch;height:3ch;background:lightgrey}' +
                  'input:not(:last-child){margin-right:1ch}'
        this
          .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
          .append(
            // spread [size=N] inputs
            ...Array(~~(this.getAttribute("size") || 5)).fill(0)
              .map((x, idx) => {
                css += `:host([select*="${idx}"]) #inp${idx} {background:lightgreen}`;
                return createElement('input', {
                  id: "inp" + idx,
                  placeholder: idx,
                  type: "text",
                  part: "input input-" + idx,
                  onclick: (evt) => console.log("clicked",idx),
                }) // createElement
              }), //Array map
            createElement('style', { innerHTML: css }),
          ) //append
      } //connectedCallback
    });
</script>
<style>
  web-component::part(input)   { border: 2px solid orange }
  web-component::part(input-1) { background: hotpink }
</style>
<web-component size="6" select="4"></web-component><hr>
<web-component select="23"></web-component><hr>
<web-component size="2"></web-component>
```

#### Be aware

The `connectedCallback` is called again when you move the Web Component in the DOM (append, drag-drop etc.)